# Windows Forms Visual. How to make const. updating fields?

Tags: c++, c, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In visual studio 2010, how can I create dynamic field (the one that constantly updates) for example if I want to add DateTime::Now.ToString() in label and want it to update itself each second. How is that possible (tried with for but it just constantly updated and did not display anything).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to update the field using one of the asynchronous thread types (probably [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)). Remember when updating the form from another thread, you'll need to use [Form::Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to prevent errors and allow the redraw function to run.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a direction where to search? but could you give me an example not from msdn?